# How to configure time formatting in Wallaby/Phantom?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs, wallaby.js

I've been trying to do some time formatting within a unit test, and noticed an inconsistency between `Jasmine` and when using `Wallaby`. I'm trying to figure out why this is. If I take the following example:

```
var options = { year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "numeric" };
console.log(new Date("01/01/2013").toLocaleDateString("en-gb", options));
```

Running this in Chrome using Jasmine I get the following output `1 Jan 2013`.
If I log this through Wallaby however I get `Tuesday, January 01, 2013`.

I've read that I can configure things such as the environment and set flags for `PhantomJS` that's used underneath - but I'm not sure what to set. I know that I can modify the locale using the `TZ` variable - but I'm already specifying the locale as `en-gb` in my example.

Is it possible to configure the formatting? Am I looking at the wrong thing to configure this formatting?

Comment: All PhantomJS versions seem to support only long months and PhantomJS 1.x seems to always include the weekday (not PhantomJS 2.0.0).